# ADB does not recognize device (LG X Charge)

Tags: adb

I am not able to get [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) to recognize my device. Here is my setup:

- USB debugging is enabled under Developer Options
- Use USB Connection for File Transfer (Transfer Documents and media files to the connected device)
- In device manager on Windows 10, under Portable Devices I see LG-M322. I have tried right-clicking on it -> update driver -> browse my computer for driver software -> C:\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver -> Next. It says the best drivers for your device are already installed. screenshot below
  [image]

But when I run `adb devices` I don't see my device:

```
C:\Users\me>adb devices -l
List of devices attached
```

I have tried killing the server many times as well as unplug the device and connect it again. I am able to transfer files to the device using windows explorer.

My phone is running Android version 7.0. Build number NRD90U. Software Version M322V10n.

How can I fix this please? I have tried similar posts and tried all the things they mention (the bullet points above).

Comment: On your device, while it is plugged in, can you tell me if you see a USB options notification?  You should be able to select this notification and choose between some options like; File Transfer, PTP, Charge Only, ETC...

Comment: Yes that is bullet #2 in my question. I have selected File Transfer

Comment: If you want your device to show up when you type `adb devices`, you don't want "file transfer" selected.

Answer (score 0):

changing the USB Mode to **Photo Transfer** worked

```
C:\Users\Downloads>adb devices
List of devices attached
LGM322c17168b6  device
```